# How can I enable Java 14 records in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-14, java-record

I cannot create Java record class in IntelliJ, and I could not find the option to enable it.

Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: IntelliJ is pretty good at broadcasting and documenting their feature releases. All it would have needed is to search it over the net. Besides the current question, doesn't have any debugging details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure you have an updated version of the IntelliJ IDEA (2020.1 or later);
2. Go to the Project Structure and set your *Project Language Level* to `Java 14` (remember, as well, to set `Java 14` as your *Project SDK*, if not done yet).

See more [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/03/java-14-and-intellij-idea/#:%7E:text=Configure%20IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.1%20to,IntelliJ%20IDEA%20and%20configure%20it.).

Comment: Given records were a preview feature in Java 14 (the feature was finalized with Java 16), and IntelliJ only supports preview features of actively supported Java versions, this will no longer work. And even when it did work, this answer is missing the step to set the language level to _"14 (preview)"_ (which, again, is no longer possible in current IntelliJ versions).